# Can a series RLC circuit have an unstable natural response?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: fig 2]

I'm looking at this exercise in a book for the natural response of an RLC series circuit without a voltage source driving the circuit and they show that the circuit is unstable.

**Is it ever possible for an RLC series to be unstable if it doesn't have an input voltage source?**  Seems to me the resistor would always bring the voltage down over time without the input voltage to put it back up again.

See example:

[image: fig 1]

Comment: Your intuition is correct, that comes straight out of energy conservation. Unless something is putting energy into this system is should respond with a decaying oscillation until there is no current or voltage in any of the components.

Comment: @jDAQ What on earth is the text talking about then?

Comment: The "solving we have" step is wrong, look, the initial conditions are changing the dynamics of the system, that is not possible for a linear time-invariant system.

Comment: @DKNguyen this book needs to pay their revisors more, this is a very "daring" proof with some gross algebraic error.

Comment: The characteristic equation is \$s^2+\frac{R}{L}s+\omega_0^2=0\$ where \$\omega_0=\frac1{\sqrt{L\,C}}\$. From this, I set \$\alpha=\frac12\frac{R}{L}\$ and \$\zeta=\frac{\alpha}{\omega_0}=\frac{R}2\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}\approx 0.3536\$. So it's going to be under-damped behavior.

Comment: _"I'm looking at this exercise in a book"_ - Which book?

Comment: Circuit Analysis Demystified, by David Mcmahon, the source of all his questions, as it seems...

Comment: An ethical aside: introductory texts take on the high burden of being correct, lest thousands of students collectively waste tens of thousands of hours figuring out that yes, that's a mistake in the text. I know I wasted a few days over the years! As a student, it's reasonable to first suspect your own work, expecting that if you did it right, it should "agree with the book".  We had Maple and Mathematica for a very long time now - IMHO all authors of such basic texts should have all the derivations done using a CAS to ensure they are at least not wildly incorrect...

Comment: But that's also part of engineering culture. 20 years ago there have been lots of engineering students in my year who had no ability to automate anything using by then decades-old free tools. So, expecting someone who is not on speaking terms with software automation to think of automating the error-prone tasks in textbook authorship is a long shot. Thus, it's very important today that all engineers are in fact able to not merely "code", but code to make their life easier, leveraging the variety of software tools available.

Answer (score 5):

This is an algebraic error of the author. Look at the proper step that the author should have done in the "solving we have" part,

$$LC(s^2V_C(s)-sV_0)+RC(sV_C(s)-V_0)+V_C(s) = 0,$$

$$LC(s^2+sRC+1)V_C(s)-sLCV_0-RCV_0= 0,$$

$$LC(s^2+sRC+1)V_C(s) = sV_0+RCV_0 = (sLC+RC)V_0,$$

$$V_C(s) = \frac{sLC+RC}{LC(s^2+sRC+1)}V_0 = \frac{sLC+RC}{s^2+sRC+1} \frac{V_0}{LC}.$$

Using that \$R = 2\$, \$C = \tfrac{1}{2}\$, \$L = 4\$ and \$ V_0 = 2\$

$$V_C(s) = \frac{2s+1}{s^2+s+1} \frac{V_0}{2} = \frac{2s+1}{s^2+s+1}.$$

As you can see, the initial conditions cannot change the dynamics (poles) of a linear system. Unlike what your *book* states, the poles will be at

$$s_0 = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1-4}}{2} = \frac{-1 \pm j\sqrt{3}}{2},$$

and the system is stable and the oscillations will eventually decay.

ps:

Whoever wrote this got the result that a passive system was "unstable" and glanced at the fact that
\$ \lambda(s) = LCs^2+(RC-LCv(0))s+1 \$, meaning, the **linear** system was not linear (for different starting conditions the "poles" would change, and for nonlinear system the whole idea of poles does not exist/work).

Comment: yeah...that's got to be where the mistake is at...

Comment: @pico If jDAQ got the answer you want, you may as well select it to save the time of others. (As with all your other questions. Just a reminder.) To me, the characteristic equation is sufficient and I don't need to bother further. But it's nice to also see jDAQ's extension. What more do you want? Save the time of others and get busy with selecting answers to your questions, where they meet your expectations, so that you don't unnecessarily distract others' time.

Comment: @jDAQ I liked your original answer more to be honest lol

Comment: Since extraordinary conclusions require extraordinary proof, if I was writing what the author wrote, but in a homework solution, never mind a book, I'd have been questioning the results and looking really hard for my own errors. The circuit can be prototyped with reasonable fidelity to the idealized model, so if the model shows something absurd, perhaps the modeller made a mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you could get an arbitrarily increasing output from that circuit with no input and no power, (and with R positive,) you'd have a perpetual motion machine.  Build it; if it works, off to the patent office!

Comment: its possible,,, you just need a negative ohm resistor... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting discussion. Shows not to trust books! Not only bodged the algebra, but confusing the Laplace transform with the Laplace transfer function.
Going back to the question:
*Is it ever possible for an RLC series to be unstable if it doesn't have an input voltage source? ...*
The no-source circuit is asymptotically stable since current and voltage(s) will decay to zero from any initial values.
The circuit is also stable if you add a voltage source. Its BIBO stable (Bounded Input Bounded Input), since for any bounded voltage source, the current and voltage(s) are bounded ... they can't fly off to infinity.
To determine stability, you don't have to test both asymptotic stability and BIBO stability...if system is asymptotically stable it is also BIBO stable and vice versa. So, an RLC circuit with a finite, uncontrolled, voltage (or current) source is always stable. Theoretically, a controlled source can make it unstable. As far as I know, controlled sources don't exist - they are fictitious sources that are useful for analysing certain circuits

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the resistor from the RLC, and just consider an ideal LC circuit with an initial voltage across the capacitor and zero input voltage source, then, its possible for the circuit to be **marginally stable**.

For an ideal LC circuit, the output voltage across the capacitor would be:

$$V_c(s) = \frac{\omega_0^2 V_i(s) - v_c(t=0)}{s^2 + \omega_0^2}$$

where:

$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$$

And the output the poles of V_c(s) are purely imaginary and consequently the circuit has a **marginally stable** for the output voltage.

$$s^2 + \omega_0^2=0$$

$$s^2 = -\omega_0^2$$

$$s = \pm \sqrt{-\omega_0^2}$$

$$s = \pm j\omega_0$$