# bode plot: calculating number of decades away from a cutoff frequency

Tags: bode-plot

(From "Circuit Analysis Demystified", David McMahon, 2008, Chapter 15, Example 15-6, and Example 16-7)

Let's say I have a Butterworth filter with cutoff frequency:

$$\omega_c$$

The stop band frequency of the filter is:

$$\omega_s = 20 \omega_c$$

how many decades is $$\omega_c$$ away from $$\omega_s$$ on the bode plot?  This book is trying to tell me its:

$$\omega_s = 2*10 * \omega_c$$

for 2 decades.... but I think its:

$$\log_{10}(20) = 1.3~\text{decades}$$

Is this book correct? See example below:

[image: circuit analysis demystified]

here's another example from the book below. I think they calculated that one wrong as well...shouldn't it be:

$$\log_2(6) = \log_{10}(6) / \log_{10}(2) = 2.58~~\text{octaves beyond the cutoff freq}$$

[image: circuit analysis demystified]

**Maybe they are just rounding up and not showing the in-between steps?**

Comment: I see you still haven’t looked at formally accepting answers yet.

Comment: well, aren't you a points monger..

Comment: @pico Accepting answers means anyone, in the future, searching for similar problems, will see this question listed with an accepted answer. The points system is more an enticement, not a dependency, but also a way to show that a certain user can be trusted to give reliable answers, or not (and anything inbetween).

Comment: @pico are you conserving your precious points to use them on something else besides accepting answers from people who've taken the time to help you?

Comment: Isn't this just semantics?

Answer (score 2):

You're right.  2 decades is a factor of 100 (not 20), and 3 octaves is a factor of 8 (not 6).  Somebody was phoning in their proofreading duties that week.

Comment: Yet another error from Circuit Analysis Demystified ...  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478176/can-a-series-rlc-circuit-have-an-unstable-natural-response

Answer (score -1):

**Example 15.6**

$$\omega_\text{linear} = 2\omega_c$$

$$\Large10^{\omega_\text{decade}} = \omega_\text{linear}$$

$$\omega_\text{decade} = \log_{10}(\omega_\text{linear})$$

$$\omega_\text{decade} = \log_{10}(2\omega_C$)$$

$$\omega_\text{decade} = \log_{10}(2) + \log_{10}(\omega_C$)$$

$$\omega_\text{decade} = \underbrace{1.3}_{\Delta\omega} + \log_{10}(\omega_C$)$$

$$\Delta | H|_{dB}=\Delta\omega_{decade} \cdot \text{(butterwoth filter slope)}$$

at high frequency the butterworth filter has a slope of $$-20 \cdot n~ dB~ /~ \text{decade}$$

where n is the filter order.

Thus:

$$\Delta | H|_{dB}=\Delta\omega_{decade} \cdot \text{(butterwoth filter slope)}$$

$$-390~ dB =(1.3~decades) \cdot (-20\cdot n~\text{db/decade})$$

$$n = \frac{390}{(1.3)(20}$$

$$n=15$$

Thus:

$$|H(\omega)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{\omega}{\omega_c})^{2\cdot 15}}}$$

$$|H(\omega)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{\omega}{\omega_c})^{30}}}$$

Its a ridiculously high order filter...but then again 390 Db is a really large attenuation,  would need to reduce the attenuation drop to get a lower order filter.

**Example 15.7**:

The same thing again, except you don't need to use octaves... it works out to the same value using decades instead of octave.

The answers I got for that problem were:

$$-80~dB = (0.7782)(-20~n~dB/decade)$$

$$n = 5.14$$

rounding up:

$$n = 6$$

$$|H(\omega)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\frac{\omega}{\omega_c})^{12}}}$$